# Nested block inside if condition django

Tags: python, django, nested, block

How can I have nested blocks inside an if condition in a Django template?

So far I've tried this but the 3 blocks are called:

```
{% if var = '1' %}
    {% block a %}active{% endblock %}
{% elif var = '2' %}
    {% block b %}active{% endblock %}
{% elif var = '3' %}
    {% block c %}active{% endblock %}       
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways of handling it. If you want it to be in a single template, then you can do this:

```
{% block a %}{% if var = '1' %}active{% else %}{{ block.super }}{%endif%}{%endblock%}
{% block b %}{% if var = '2' %}active{% else %}{{ block.super }}{%endif%}{%endblock%}
{% block c %}{% if var = '3' %}active{% else %}{{ block.super }}{%endif%}{%endblock%}
```

The other way would be to create multiple templates and determine which one to use based on `var`.

In var1.html:

```
{% block a %}active{% endblock %}
```

In var2.html:

```
{% block b %}active{% endblock %}
```

In var3.html:

```
{% block c %}active{% endblock %}
```

You could also have three different templates that you extend with the template that you're working in. You'd have your three variations with the different active element. Then in your template that would extend one of them, you'd do:

```
{% extend variable_name %}
```

Comment: I prefer to have only one template because they are very similiar and it makes them easier to edit. The first option worked perfectly. It's just missing the {% endif %}  Thanks!